# Domain Controller Policy for Azure ADDS

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, gpo, azure-ad-domain-services

I have a network where users are constantly changing their system time in order to do their work.

The problem is that whenever I try to execute commands on these machines remotely I cannot authenticate. I want to change the DC policy to [allow clock skew](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/maximum-tolerance-for-computer-clock-synchronization). As stated in the documentation `"This policy setting is configured on the domain controller."`.

Is there any way to configure the policy for ADDS machines? I cannot remote connect to them and no user have permissions to create or modify their OU GPOs.

Note: users will always have an incorrect system time, this is not going to change

Answer (score 0):

In order to administer the group policy in Azure AD domain services one of the pre-requisites is a user account that's a member of the Azure AD DC administrators group in your Azure AD tenant.